# What measurement of time is so small that it qualifies as quantum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, discrete

> Quantum mechanics (QM; also known as quantum physics, or quantum theory) is a branch of physics which deals with physical phenomena at nanoscopic scales where the action is on the order of the Planck constant.

-wiki

Time is much less finite than matter. Matter can be split to the point where it is so small that it gains the classification of nanoscopic and subatomic. However the Planck constant is a measurement of mass and time so I find it difficult to separate the measurements. What measurement of time is so small that it qualifies as quantum? Could someone clear up the misconception?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time

Comment: We don't know. Planck time and the Planck scale are hypotheticals for which absolutely no observational evidence exists. In general, since time is not a reversible process and since it is observer dependent (quanta are neither), it's not even clear why time itself should quantize. That "whatever" that may cause time may quantize, but time itself is more likely to be an averaged thermodynamic quantity of that "whatever" than a quantum phenomenon itself.

Comment: delta E * delta t >= h/4*pi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly the intention of your question, the answer you are looking for is not the Planck time. If the question is at what time scales a systems behaves as quantum rather than classical, the answer would be equivalent to at what spatial scales a measurement is quantum instead of classical. The answer depends on the system itself. There are macroscopic systems (for instance, Bose-Einstein condensates) that behave in quantum manner, but most classical examples involve small particles or molecules. Thus, there is no single answer, the range can vary  orders of magnitude if you can prepare carefully the system. The same happens with the time scale. A system behaves in a quantum manner if the measurement is smaller than the decoherence time. As with the case of spatial scale, this length of time varies with the system.

Comment: Very true. An even better example of a macroscopic quantum phenomenon are superconductors.